# NSTaggedPointerString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument in iOS13

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios13

First of all, I didn't speak English well, so I used google translator.
It turns out that this problem only occurs in ios13. It seems to be a problem somewhere in the web area, but I couldn't solve the problem. Help. Thank you.

> Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
>       *** -[NSTaggedPointerString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x19e12c98c __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x19de550a4 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x19e43f44c +[NSUserDefaults(NSUserDefaults_NSURLExtras) _web_defaultsDidChange]
3  TextInput                      0x1aa02dc2c -[TIDocumentState(StateTransitions) documentStateAfterReplacingText:withText:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x1a1f6db50 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDocumentStateForAutocorrection:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1a1f6e15c __82-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]_block_invoke_2
6  UIKitCore                      0x1a1f6dfb4 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
7  UIKitCore                      0x1a1f6d440 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
8  UIKitCore                      0x1a1f6d310 __56-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]_block_invoke
9  UIKitCore                      0x1a1f935e0 -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:]
10 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f92010 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]
11 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f9233c -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTaskOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:]
12 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f6d22c -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]
13 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f70288 -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]
14 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f70450 __38-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]_block_invoke
15 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f935e0 -[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:]
16 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f92010 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]
17 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f703fc -[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]
18 UIKitCore                      0x1a1f576d8 -[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]
19 UIKitCore                      0x1a1c61e98 -[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForKeyWindowSceneResponder:]
20 UIKitCore                      0x1a1c616b4 -[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
21 UIKitCore                      0x1a216bf64 -[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews]
22 WebKit                         0x1a5ae29b0 -[WKContentView(WKInteraction) _hideKeyboard]
23 WebKit                         0x1a5ae3394 -[WKContentView(WKInteraction) _elementDidBlur]
24 WebKit                         0x1a5ad7838 -[WKContentView(WKInteraction) endEditingAndUpdateFocusAppearanceWithReason:]
25 WebKit                         0x1a5ae06d8 -[WKContentView(WKInteraction) accessoryDone]
26 UIKitCore                      0x1a213ba44 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
27 UIKitCore                      0x1a1820ddc __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke
28 UIKitCore                      0x1a1820c68 -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]
29 UIKitCore                      0x1a213ba44 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
30 UIKitCore                      0x1a1b7f6d0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
31 UIKitCore                      0x1a1b7fa34 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
32 UIKitCore                      0x1a1b7ea50 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
33 UIKitCore                      0x1a2174d68 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
34 UIKitCore                      0x1a21760a8 -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
35 UIKitCore                      0x1a2152ae8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
36 UIKitCore                      0x1a21ca23c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue
37 UIKitCore                      0x1a21cc798 __handleEventQueueInternal
38 UIKitCore                      0x1a21c560c __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain
39 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0aa7e0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
40 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0aa738 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
41 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a9ed0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
42 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a501c __CFRunLoopRun
43 CoreFoundation                 0x19e0a48bc CFRunLoopRunSpecific
44 GraphicsServices               0x1a7f10328 GSEventRunModal
45 UIKitCore                      0x1a213a6d4 UIApplicationMain
46 smartwish                      0x1059b63d0 main + 42 (main.m:42)
47 libdyld.dylib                  0x19df2f460 start
```

Comment: Same problem here. It only happens on iOS13, using WKWebview and keyboard from web.

Comment: I can see exactly the same crash in my app, via Firebase Crashlytics crash reports. I have no solution for it yet, would be very interested to have it fixed. It seems like an issue with auto-completion in a text filed on a web form.

Comment: This looks like a bug on iOS when the user taps more than once on an auto-completion field that appears after a new email message with the code of 2-factor authentication was detected. Please check this out: http://openradar.appspot.com/7428013

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a bug on iOS when the user taps more than once on an auto-completion field that appears after a new email message with the code of 2-factor authentication was detected. Please check this out: http://openradar.appspot.com/7428013

As a quick fix, you could do the following, of course, if you have the access to the web page content where you have an input field for the one-time validation code. Disable the autocompletion for that input control, so it looks like this:

```
<input id="one-time-password-textfield" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Then you (and me) will need to keep track of that OpenRadar ticket hoping it will get fixed anytime soon ;-) Once fixed, the auto-completion can be re-enabled back in the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I try to fix this use `"autocomplete="off""`.

Please wait for my test results.

Comment: The bug still exsit - -!